# What pixel dimensions should a logo on business card be?

Tags: logo, resolution, file-format, measurement

What should the dimensions of a logo on a business card be? I'm grabbing a free logo and the card company is asking how many pixels I want the logo to be when I download the logo and I don't really understand pixels and how big it will be if I choose a certain pixel size.

Comment: Ideally it wouldn't have any.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the size in pixels that you need you simply multiply the physical size it will be by the resolution you need to supply your print artwork at...

So, say your logo needs to be 2 × 2 inches and your artwork needs to be 300 PPI; your logo would need to be 600 × 600 pixels. (Make sure you're multiplying the correct units here; PPI is "Pixels Per *Inch*" so you multiply that with the physical size *in inches*; if you have your measurements in another unit make sure to convert to the correct one first).

Something to note; if this is a one-time download and you don't have the option of re-requesting the logo at a different size at a later date then simply request it at *the largest size possible*. This means you'll be able to use it again at a larger size if needs be. Having too large an image is never a problem; a too small image *always is*.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my... Why are you looking for a formula?

Design is about making decisions, a logo could be tiny, or exceding the size of the business card as a background.

Try to use a vector logo.

An option is to hire a designer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no precise pixel size a logo "should be". The size would depend on what size you are reproducing it at, which you failed to mention.

If the logo is a raster image, then to get it really quite sharp, then you probably need to have it printed at least at 600dpi.  Logos tend to have text or shapes with sharp edges and often fine lines, unlike a photographic image where you could get by with around 300dpi.

If the logo is to be reproduced at 1" x 1", then you'd need an image at 600px x 600px for 600dpi printing.

hint: 1" x 600ppi = 600px

Note: Ideally of course, raster images shouldn't be used for logos, especially small logos. Vector images are better for logos, because these are infinitely rescalable, because they have no pixels at all.